# Port 5355 opened on the internet

Tags: networking, internet, 17.10

I have an Ubuntu box that is connected to the internet and provides ICS.

If I list the open ports by running:

```
netstat -tulnap | grep LISTEN
```

it shows me:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:445           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1419/smbd
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.2:445         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1419/smbd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:139           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1419/smbd
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.2:139         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1419/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1056/systemd-resolv
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.2:53          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1130/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.2:22          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1189/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      1056/systemd-resolv
```

where, clearly, port 5355 is open on the internet.

**Does this open port pose any threat?**

Comment: Please provide OS/release details, you have tagged an long past *end-of-life* release so if 17.10 is your release, you may have other unsecured holes in your system.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `systemd-resolved` *that provides network name resolution to local applications via a D-Bus interface*. See [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-resolved)

Although I don't quiet get why it is running on a public address. This does not seem to be the default. One could firewall the port or re-configure the service.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a threat.

It is link-local Multicast name resolution provided by systemd.
Details are here : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-Local_Multicast_Name_Resolution

Comment: Is it required to have that port open for normal network operations?

Comment: Should we block access from Internet with the firewall ?